# How to Create Custom Template data in Azure API Management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, dotliquid

I am newbie. I want to edit template and applying role on template that which element of the developer portal is shown to which user according to the roles. there are two panes one for client side and other is template data pane in which it has a data which is further uses on other pane by using dotliquid syntax. kindly guide me how i can generate the template data according to my requirement.

### Template Data

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unfortunately, the variables available through the templates are fixed and not editable. Having user context information across all templates is something we are considering - please add your requirement and vote for it over at http://aka.ms/apimwish.

Many thanks

Matt